# ssh to instances on IBM-cloud using private IP

Tags: ip, cloud

I am creating virtual server instances (by using my custom image) on IBM CLOUD.

after the VMs are provisioned, they get a private IP (10.X.X.X),

and can get a floating IP (public IP) that Internet can access it.

How can I make free access to that VMs from my company network without opening it to the world?

or alternatively, how to make that VM get private IP from my company subnet,
So that every entity in the company will have access to the machines and vice versa but without a public IP.

for clarify: i need SSH to those VMs with their private IP.

Thank's for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make free access to that VMs from my company network without opening it to the world?

You are literally describing the definition of a VPN! So, you need a VPN.

That's easy: Just give your company network an ingress point, e.g. with a single VM that has a  wireguard interface, and set routing to the internal VM addresses to go through that VM.